# Asynchronous Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Whenever Lets say i have a signal comes variable that updating continiously from outside of my code I want my code a third party application. Lets say that it changes between 0 to immediately stop 100. For example:

```
import time
while True:
    try:
        print("message one")
        time.sleep(10)
        print("message two")
        time.sleep(10)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("message three")
```

When I press Ctrl+C And i have a main code that works in my program's 3rd second, I a loop also continiously. So i want to this loop immediately print "message three" stops when my variable is more than, lets say, 50. How can I i do it  ? In this message it only prints "message three" after 20 seconds, but I want to interrupt the routine.

Lets say i have a variable that updating continiously from a third party application. Lets say that it changes between 0 to 100. And i have a main code that works in a loop also continiously. So i want this loop immediately stops when my variable is more than, lets say, 50. How can i do it ?

Edit:

Actually what i want to do is this:

```
import time

while True:
    dothisfunction()
    time.sleep(10)
    doanotherfunction()
    time.sleep(10)
    alsodoit()
    time.sleep(10)
    andalsodoit()
    time.sleep(10)
```

lets say this is my main script. i want to use *KeyboardInterrupt* to interrupt this script whenever i want, NOT THE END OF LOOP.

Comment: it only lacks an exit() or raise or break inside except block

Comment: yes but how can i immediately exit the loop when some kind of external interrupt comes? try except method just an example. i think there is another way about external interrupts.

Comment: @MustafaGökçe what kind of "external interrupt" are you thinking about? You asked specifically about the code you presented, and that was answered. Please [edit] your post to explain **exactly** what you're talking about, as the solution will likely vary depending on what you mean. A `KeyboardInterrupt` is very different from a message being received by a server, for example.

Comment: i edited it. thanks.

Comment: @MustafaGökçe If you press CTRL-C, control transfers *immediately* to the except.  It does not finish out the loop first.  If you then have a break statement in the except clause, the while will stop as well.

Answer (score 1):

It should immediately print `message three` when CTRL-C is pressed, but if you want it to stop, add a `break` to leave the `while` loop.

```
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("message three")
    break
```

If you add the try outside the `while`, you don't even need the break.  CTRL-C will exit the loop immediately.

Here's an example with timestamps in seconds:

```
import time
try:
    while True:
        print(time.time(),"message one")
        time.sleep(5)
        print(time.time(),"message two")
        time.sleep(5)
        print(time.time(),"message three")
        time.sleep(5)
        print(time.time(),"message four")
        time.sleep(5)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print(time.time(),"CTRL-C!")
```

Output:

```
1484687761.801528 message one
1484687766.80314 message two           # 5 seconds later.
1484687767.26655 CTRL-C!               # .4 seconds later...didn't finish loop
```

Comment: yes but how can i immediately exit the loop when some kind of external interrupt comes? try except method just an example. i think there is another way about external interrupts.

Comment: @MustafaGökçe just put exit() instead of break

Comment: @MustafaGökçe Edited my answer with an example.  From your comments you think that the loop doesn't exit immediately, so I added timestamps in an example.